# Objective c Thread/Runloop/Concurrency consideration

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Consider the following Class:

```
@interface TaskScheduler ()

@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *tasks;

@end

@implementation TaskScheduler

- (void)addTask:(Task *)task
{
    [_tasks setObject:task forKey:task.id];
}

- (void)cancelTask:(NSString *)id
{
    [_tasks removeObjectForKey:id];
}

- (void)runTask:(Task *)task
{
    // run task in a background concurrent global dispatch queue
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundConcurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

    void (^dispatchBlock)() = ^void(){
        BOOL success = task.taskBlock(); // typedef BOOL (^TaskBlock)();
        if (success)
        {
            [self cancelTask:task.id];
        }
    };
    dispatch_async(backgroundConcurrentQueue, dispatchBlock);
}

- (void)didUpdateSystemUpdateValue
{
    // some other class has a `dispatch_source_t` timer that fires every second and calls this delegate API

    if (shouldRunTask)
    {
        for (Task *task in _tasks.allValues)
        {
            [self runTask:task];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Now please notice how I am cancelling a task inside the dispatch queue block call itself.

I am a bit confused here — is there any issue in the `runTask:` call? I am cancelling the task if it succeeds inside the `dispatchBlock` that runs using the global dispatch queue. Only tasks inside `tasks` can run.

The only issue I can see that the same task can be run multiple times if some condition holds true unless the task succeeds in one of the dispatch calls after which it will won't exist in the queue (or a dictionary of tasks).

EDIT: I have made changes to the original question. I never intended that the rest of the design would need to be part of the question. The question can be answered without the newest changes but just in case.

Comment: I think you need to give us more code. As it stands your example doesn't make much sense. For example, you declare an `NSMutableDictionary` called `tasks` which you then don't use.  You add and remove tasks into a dictionary called `_tasks` which doesn't get referenced anywhere else.  Cancelling a task only removes the task from the dictionary but does nothing else.  How do tasks get started? What is the point of `addTask`? Why are you cancelling tasks when they have completed successfully?

Comment: Accessing `_tasks`—via `addTask` (main thread, presumably) and `cancelTask` (background thread)—from multiple threads without any synchronization is a bad idea.  When `taskBlock()` completes you should post another block to the main queue to call `cancelTask`.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a step back and describe what you're trying to accomplish here (and help us understand why the basic dispatch queues and/or operation queues are insufficient). Perhaps edit the question with practical example of how you anticipate using your task scheduler.

Comment: Please see the updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be assuming that it's safe for `-setObject:forKey:` and `-removeObjectForKey:` to be called concurrently from two different threads, and it is categorically *not* safe. You need additional synchronization. The fact that you wrap the `-removeObjectForKey:` call inside your `-cancelTask:` method, and call it from your `-runTask:` method is irrelevant. `NSMutableDictionary` is not safe for concurrent operations from multiple threads no matter how many other methods you wrap it in, if none of those wrapping methods provide any synchronization which none of those copied here do.

Comment: I see. So if I provide a safe implementation of `NSMutableDictionary`, I won't have any obvious issues.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.